# angularjs : disable a button and show popup instead

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this button :
html:

```
    <button nav-direction="back" class="button yy" ui-sref="app.result" ui-sref-active="currentNav" ng-click="navResult()">
      Board
    </button>
```

I would like it to display a popup if a certain condition is, else I would like it to go to another page.

I need to keep the benefit of the class in ui-sref-active to show that this is the current page.

controller.js

```
  $scope.navResult = function (){
    console.log(sessionService.get('computed'));
    if (sessionService.get('computed')) {
      $scope.go('app.result');
    } else {
      //popup to user to tap on a board
      //$scope.go('app.compute');
      var popupConfig = {
        title: 'Beware! ;)',
        template: 'Tap on a board below'
      };
      var popup = $ionicPopup.show(popupConfig);
      ClosePopupService.register(popup);
    }
  }


  $scope.go = function ( state ) {
    // console.log("go has been launched with : "+ state)
    $state.go( state );
  };
```

Comment: And how is your code currently behaving?

Comment: For now this code goes to result page anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You just use an ng-click method instead of a ui-sref, and go to the state from there.

```
<button nav-direction="back" ng-class="{'your-class':classCondition}" class="button yy" ng-click="navResult()">
      Board
</button>
```

Then in your controller....

```
$scope.navResult = function(){
    if(something){
       $scope.classCondition = false;
       //code to display popup here
    } else {
        $state.go('app.result')
    }
}
```

You can pass any valid state into $state.go, so if you ever want to check for a condition and perform some logic BEFORE you redirect to another page, use it inside a $scope method instead of just using the straight ui-sref.

Comment: yes but the thing is I am loosing the ui-sref-active functionality with this

Comment: Well since ui-sref-active would necessitate disabling the button anyway, could you use `ng-class` to add and remove your classes instead?

Comment: I guess I could, could you show me in your code please ?

Comment: I just edited my answer so you can see what that would look like.

Comment: ok I see, do you know how to get the current state programmatically in the controller to implement classCondition ?

Comment: Yup, you can use `$state.current` and it should be a property on that object.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work as expected... Isn't a way to keep the ui-sref feature ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92176/discussion-between-oceansonpluto-and-louis).